# How to Get URL Parameters And Use In 'iframe'?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I need to get `URL` parameters and use in `Iframe`:

URL example: `www.example.com?id=123&user=XXX`

So, my page have parameters in URL and i need to get those (ex: 123, XXX)

and use in iframe (you can see below src link with parameters).

```
<iframe id="JotFormIFrame-9262" style="width: 1px; min-width: 100%; height: 539px; border: none;" title="Custom Webview" src="https://form.com?i=123&u=XXX" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
```

i've tried some php code like to capture URL parameters with

```
<form action="example.com" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user;?>" name="user">
    </form>
```

and php to use them

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id'];?>
```

But didn't work

Comment: Show the code you are using to get the URL parameters.

Comment: Is it `www.example.com/id=123&user=XXX` or `www.example.com/?id=123&user=XXX`?

Comment: Do you need to change the keys (e.g. `user` -> `u`) or just leave them as is?

Comment: www.example.com?id=123&user=XXX @KoalaYeung

Comment: I'm asking which code i can use @bassxzero

Comment: I can use same keys name, is not important.  @KoalaYeung

Comment: Have you checked `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`? You may use it directly in building your iframe url.

Answer (score 0):

As far I have understood, what you can do is first you can get the parameters using $_GET and then store them in variable.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

And then pass them in iFrame URL

Comment: <form action="url" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user;?>" name="user">
    </form>

Should i use this to capture URL parameters first?

Comment: Yes, get the parameters first, and them use them in iFrame